# angular-ui-tree: dropped location + catch dropped event in directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-directive, angular-ui-tree

I'm using [angular-ui-tree](http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/) for building a tree of items in my app. 
I'm using its drag & drop feature and I need to know when & where (on what element) the dropping occurs.

For example, I drag item1, and drop it on a panel. I want the panel to display the item name. (each item has a name property). the panel is just a simple div with text inside.

I saw in the documentations that I can access the "dropped" event in my controller. But I don't understand how to change the panel content according to the dragged & dropped item.

Answer (score 15):

As in [documentations](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree)  $callbacks (type: Object)

> $callbacks is a very important property for angular-ui-tree. When some
>   special events trigger, the functions in $callbacks are called. The
>   callbacks can be passed through the directive.

you define the events in a treeOptions collection

```
     myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
     // here you define the events in a treeOptions collection
      $scope.treeOptions = {
        accept: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {
          return true;
        },
        dropped: function(e) {
          console.log (e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue);     
        }
      };

    });
```

then in your tree div add **callbacks="treeOptions"** which you defined above in the controller

```
<div ui-tree callbacks="treeOptions">
  <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="nodes">
    <li ng-repeat="node in nodes" ui-tree-node>{{node.title}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

then you can access the old parent from here

```
e.source.nodeScope.$parentNodeScope.$modelValue
```

and you can access the new parent from here

```
e.dest.nodesScope.$parent.$modelValue
```

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with the version, I am using Angular UI Tree v2.1.5. And your solution only works if I change this: <div ui-tree callbacks="treeOptions"> into this: <div ui-tree="treeOptions">

Comment: sorry for being late. I'm using a [newer version](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/releases/tag/v2.2.0) and it was working great

Comment: @IbrahimKais Can you get the position of the child element? i need to sort the tree, because of this i need to get the position of where the child node is located between the other nodes. can't find a way to get this

Comment: @ DaCh: what is your version and how do you sort?

Comment: How can i get curruent  dragged element values in dropped callback

Comment: @Coder you can navigate inside the event object (e) to find what you want

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys i just found it !

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
            dropped: function (event) {
             //To catch the event after dragged

             //Value of model which is moving
             event.source.nodeScope.$modelValue;

             //Source Parent from where we are moving model
             event.source.nodeScope.$parentNodeScope.$modelValue;

             //Destination Parent to where we are moving model
             //Edit: Use "nodesScope" instead of "nodeScope" for dest object 
             event.dest.nodesScope.$nodeScope.$modelValue;
         }};
```

Hope it works for you too:)

Answer (score 1):

You access the "dropped" item like this.

```
$scope.elOptions = {
    dropped: function(e) {
        console.log (e.source.nodeScope.$modelValue);     
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Addional information which might be useful can be found on this issue of the project : https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/issues/272

For example in my case, I was dragging from one tree to another one, and in this case, the dropped function must be overriden in the SOURCE tree options (and not the DESTINATION one like I initially thought).

The discussion in the related issue helped me a lot to find this out.